# Would wooden bullets work?

Tags: weapons

This article claims that the infusion of wood particles into the vampires bloodstream will cause blood clotting and eventually a stroke and other maladies for a vampires. This as opposed to other articles claiming that the purpose of the stake is to bind the vampire to the ground thus preventing the vampire from rising. With this in mind I think a good size wooden projectile held in place by a nylon sabot and fired from a low velocity rifle such as a 45/70 could be used to install a decent size piece of wood into a vampire at a safe distance. Using a lever action rifle one could insure reliable function while using a low power load with a velocity under 800 fps so as not to destroy the projectile and prevent over penetration. Thus leaving the wooden projectile in the vampires body and possibly even splintered inside its body which should increase its effectiveness. Any thoughts on this are welcome. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding SE!   While we do enjoy answering questions, Googling for "wooden bullets" reveals plenty of articles already about whether they're practical and what their limitations are.  You might want to review them first to help focus your question so that we can provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: This site isn't a discussion site. We're not here to share our thoughts and opinions on various subjects. Can you [edit] this so that you're asking one specific answerable question?

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan SE's goal is to become result #1 for every Google query. We need answers here in order to get there.

Comment: I know *just who to ask*.  There's a guy on Youtube who specializes in testing bullets made out of weird substances.

Comment: I was the last close voter and I'd like to explain why. @sphennings is right, our [tour] clearly states we're not a discussion forum. Our [help/on-topic] states that you're supposed to ask practical, specific, reasonably objective, and answerable questions. You haven't really asked a question: you presented a solution (contrary to the [help/dont-ask]'s rules) and asked our opinion. Will it work? Sure... it's your world, you set the rules, so obviously it will work. Is there a problem? Because you seem to only be asking if people like your idea, and that's not a valid question here.

Answer (score 8):

## Shiver Me Timbers!

A [shiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiver_my_timbers) is a piece of wooden shrapnel sparred off the inside of a ship, typically when struck externally with a cannon ball. It was a terrifying threat, which is why it was used to denote something frightening. Certainly, splinters of wood can be terrifying weapons.

[Wooden bullets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_bullet) have been used before in warfare, and aren't terribly effective. But they DO work, and can kill people, so if they have specific efficacy against vampires, then they could be used. The actual usefulness against fictional vampires would be up to you.

As a laboratory professional, I will tell you that wood really does work to stimulate clot formation, so in a species with abnormal hematology, wood isn't the most outlandish secret weapon. If a tube of blood used to produce serum won't clot, one of the ways to stimulate it to clot is to stick wooden sticks (commonly used to wring out fibrin clots) into the tube and then allow the sticks to act as clotting surfaces to start clot formation. So a bullet (even a frangible one) that blew apart internally into tiny fragments and slivers would create a clotting stimulator. In a normal person, this clotting at the site of a wound would be normal and expected. For a vampire with abnormal hematology, this could lead to [disseminated intravascular coagulopathy](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health-topics/disseminated-intravascular-coagulation#:%7E:text=Disseminated%20intravascular%20coagulation%20(DIC)%20is,blood%20clotting%20process%20become%20overactive.), a condition where the body starts uncontrollably clotting, paradoxically resulting in uncontrolled bleeding as the bodies clotting factor supplies and platelets become depleted.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you seek is complicated.  Most answers involving vampires are, but in this case more than most.

A wooden stake through the heart can entrap a vampire in motionless paralysis, indistinguishable from death.  That paralysis can imprison the vampire in their own bodies for ages, allowing them to return to undead animation only after the wood has been removed.  But for a wooden weapon to have this effect, it has to be dead wood.  Just any branch, ripped from a living tree during a fight, won't do.  It has to have been separate from its living roots for long enough for all life to depart from its dry fibrous corpse. Many a would be vampire hunter has met an early end by trusting in green wood stakes.

The reasoning behind this little known requirement, lies in the nature of vampiric un-life.  Vampirism is as much an exercise of willpower as a contagious disease.  It is an antagonistic expression of an entity's desire to live, overwhelming the demands of death and decay.  The being who is the vampire, remains animate and aware, because they refuse to accept the reality of their own death. As long as their conviction to live is blind to the demands of their mortality, and while they are supported by regular infusions of new living blood, they continue to walk the night.

With this understanding of vampirism in hand, the mechanism behind popular vampire-killing practices are easier to understand.

A wooden stake through the heart and/or the drinking of dead man's blood, both work because they introduce an absolute example of death to a body which is trying to ignore death's reality.  The dead matter's presence within their body proves that death is real on a fundamental level which their vampiric hunger cannot deny.  Normal steel or lead bullets cannot offer such proof because their base materials were never alive.  But anything which once lived and now is fully dead can, at least temporarily, overpower the vampire's will, if delivered close enough to its heart.

Holy water and crosses use the same mechanism to lesser effect, but only for formerly Christian vampires.  Specific to the Christian mythos is the accomplishment of Jesus defeating death.  When a believing vampire is reminded of the divine authority necessary to truly defeat death, they come to doubt their own abilities to do so.  This weakens and repels them from the presence of the holy reminders.

Sunlight works via the exact opposite effect.  As the source of all life energy on Earth, the sunlight pours surging life force into the vampire's nervous system, flooding circuits which are already charged with the energy of will power.  The sudden inrush of energy burns out the vampire's brain then floods out into the undead flesh, setting it ablaze.

As for the other ways that vampires can be killed, such as incinerations, decapitation and wood-chipper style dissection, these more drastic methods rely on less subtle mechanisms.  Simply put, there is a limit to human or even vampiric will power.

So to answer your question... Yes, a wooden bullet can kill a vampire, but only if it is made of old dead wood, and only if it remains within the vampire's body after impact.

Happy Hunting!